# How to connect IBM Voice Gateway or voice agent to other APIs

Tags: watson, ibm-voice-gateway

I am working on voice agent solution by IBM. I need to understand how can I connect it to database to do verification example policy number. When I created voice agent service it bind it-self with other services like speech to text, text to speech, conversation. Now how can I create a layer in between to get the intent and invoke outside API or connect to database. Is there any way to connect and get data from other api with conversation dialogs. it would be great if some one can guide. I want voice agent to connect to other api to retrieve insurance values and so-forth. Please advise. Thanks S

Answer (score 1):

The architecture you're looking for is the following:

[Service Orchestration Engine (SOE)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4U29/images/arch-selfservice-soe.png)

Essentially its a sort of proxy that stands between the Voice Gateway and the Watson Conversation service.

We have a few samples on our Github repository that will help you get started: https://github.com/WASdev/sample.voice.gateway/tree/master/soe

In the Voice Agent service there should be an option to choose a Service Orchestration Engine - https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/voice-agent/managing.html#managing